# Rails: How I can pass variables to template resolver

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
# home_controller.rb
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  prepend_view_path MyResolver.instance

  def some_action
    my_variable = true
    render :some_action, my_variable: my_variable
  end
end

# my_resolver.rb
class MyResolver < ActionView::Resolver
  include Singleton

  protected

  def find_templates(state, prefix, partial, details)
    # do_something if my_variable
  end
end
```

How I can pass `my_variable` from controller action to the template resolver as `render` options?

Answer (score 0):

what kind of information is it that you need to pass down into the resolver? that does not look like a good pattern to me.

why is you resolver a singleton? is that on purpose?

what you can do is letting a before action handle your issue:

```
before_action :handle_resolver

private

def handle_resolver
  prepend_view_path MyResolver.new(your_variable)
end
```